# Need Help C# - Expected catch or finally + cannot be applied to operands

Tags: c#, try-catch, finally

```
           MyProject.MyForms.m_FormBeingCreated.Add(typeof(T), null);
                try
                {
                    try
                    {
                        result = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                        return result;
                    }
                    object arg_96_0;
                    TargetInvocationException expr_9B = arg_96_0 as TargetInvocationException;
                    int arg_B8_0;
                    if (expr_9B == null)
                    {
                        arg_B8_0 = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TargetInvocationException ex = expr_9B;
                        ProjectData.SetProjectError(expr_9B);
                        arg_B8_0 = (((ex.InnerException != null) > false) ? 1 : 0);
                    } 
                        endfilter(arg_B8_0);
                }
                finally
                {
                    MyProject.MyForms.m_FormBeingCreated.Remove(typeof(T));
                }
            }
            result = Instance;
            return result;
        }
```

/// What have i done wrong?

Keep getting errors about: Expected catch or finally @object arg_96_0;

Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool' @ex.InnerException !=null)

The name 'endfilter' does not exist in the current context. @endfilter(arg_B8_0);

Comment: Did you read the docs on Try/Catch?

Comment: how can a bool be bigger than a bool?

Comment: Those error texts are really clear! What is your question? One `try` has no `catch` or `finally`. One greater-than sign tries to compare two Boolean expressions. And one identfier `endfilter` does not exist in the context; could be a casing issue (is it `endFilter` or `EndFilter`?).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - well, `Bool` has one bigger letter than `bool`. That has to be it!

Comment: This is a bit crazy, I inherited some code that has the same code from above. The above is not hand written code.  I looks like it was created by some kind of generator.  Mine has the same code, but arg and expr number are different.  The class is decorated with: [StandardModule, HideModuleName, GeneratedCode("MyTemplate", "8.0.0.0")]

This syntax must have compiled at one point... or maybe it got mutated by some kind of generator before compilation?

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is with this line of code

```
arg_B8_0 = (((ex.InnerException != null) > false) ? 1 : 0);
```

In C# a boolean cannot be greater than or less than, so try changing that to

```
arg_B8_0 = (((ex.InnerException != null) != false) ? 1 : 0);
```

Also, as pointed out by Jeroen and others in comments, this piece of code is not very clean and is doing some evaluations it doesn't need to do.

```
arg_BB_0 = ex.InnerException != null ? 1 : 0;
```

This is a much better way to write the expression and achieve the same goal.

Your next issue is that all try statements must be accompanied by a catch or finally statement.
Try reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) article on MSDN about proper use of try-catch blocks.

As far as getting an error that says endfilter doesn't exist in the current context, this means that you need to check the scope of where endfilter is declared. endfilter is probably not declared where it accessible in the current scope. MSDN can again be helpful here, [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a good place to get started understanding scope.

Comment: `arg_BB_0 = ex.InnerException != null ? 1 : 0;` is a lot clearer.

Comment: `try` blocks do not always need to be accompanied by a `catch` block.  A `finally` block is just as valid

Comment: @JeroenVannevel agreed, but I didn't want to make too many changes to the original statement.